# Send device GPS-location through a single SMS

Tags: android, gps, sms, location, locationmanager

I have really tried to look for code and info, and in fact my code is in part based on other questions and answers from this site. Despite that, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
This code is inside a background service. Which I try to do with this code is basically send an SMS with your GPS-based location in cycles of gpsTimeValue. I'm aware Thread.sleep(time) is not an accurate way to measure time but it is not important.

```
if (locateMode)
// start location manager
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// entering locate mode
while (locateMode) {
    handler.post(new DisplayToast("Entering locate mode"));

    // check value of sleep time
    gpsTimeValue = Integer.parseInt(pref.getString("gps_time_value", getString(R.string.gpsTimeDefault))) * 6000;

    // update notification
    msg = "Starting GPS cycle with " + gpsTimeValue;
    handler.post(new DisplayToast(msg));
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(msg);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId,
    notificationBuilder.build());

    // send location sms
    sendLocationSMS(pref.getString("send_to_number", ""),locationManager);

    // sleep
    try {
        Thread.sleep(gpsTimeValue);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // check location mode
    if (pref.getString("locate_mode", "OFF").equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
        locateMode = false;
        handler.post(new DisplayToast("Exiting locate mode"));
    }
}
```

And this is the code for sendLocationSMS. I want explicitly the GPS based location:

```
private void sendLocationSMS(final String sendToNumber,
                             LocationManager locationManager) {

    handler.post(new DisplayToast("Seting up SMS to number: "+ sendToNumber));

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the listener
            String loc = location.toString();
            String message = "Location" + loc;

            handler.post(new DisplayToast(message));

            if (!sendToNumber.isEmpty()) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                        sendToNumber, null,message,null, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras) {}
    };
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                                   0,0, locationListener);
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, locationListener, null);

}
```

So, every toast (I toast with handler.post(newDisplay(message))) is showed except the code inside onLocationChange. I see in the phone how the location is being somehow activated (I suppose because of the listener setup) but no message is sent and no location is produced. I have tried with both requestLocationUpdates and requestSingleUpdate.

Among others, I have the permissions related with this code in the manifest as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Every other part of all the code in my app works like a charm, except for this. It's driving me nuts, I don't know how to solve it. Please, any advice will be very welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this must help you to get location details through message

locationText = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();

smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, locationText, null, null);